# JS doesn't work on JADE

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I've done a lot of research and I'm totally lost on how to move forward.

I'm doing some project using Jade and Python/Django and my JavaScript doesn't work. It doesn't matter if I use JavaScript or JQuery in Jade or if I put it in it's own separate JS file then call the files.

I decided to do some test in little files to understand how it works but, I can't get my minor tests to work.

These are the files I've been using:

**Layout**

```
doctype html
html(lang='es')
    head        
        block title

    // body
    body
        #main
            block content
        script(src='/static/js/modals.js')
```

**Not sure what this file does:**

```
extends prueba-layout.jade

block title
    title esto es un titulo
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="")

block content
    p esto es un contenido asasadasdasdds
    button#btn click me to open something
```

**first JQuery --> FAIL**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        alert('asdasd');
    });
});
```

**second JQuery --> FAIL**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
            alert('asdasd');
        });
```

**3th JS --> SUCCESS**

```
alert("Testing");
```

***ALL OF THIS FILES ARE .JS***

**4th JS --> fail that's .jade and included**

```
script(text/javascript).
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
```

Can someone explain why my JS isn't being called at all?

Comment: Did you include jQuery

Comment: yes... I already fixfed it!

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED:**

I was calling some modals, them were ubicated in another .jade than the buttons (anyway both rendered on the same url) but It doesn't work so

Put the "button" or "what active the **JS**" in the same .jade than the "content" you want to show (the modals in my case)